# How to check if input is text

Tags: python, string, input

Hi all I am pretty new to python coding but have recently stumbled upon a problem, when asking people for names the program will allow numbers, is there a simple way to fix this.

My code is something like this:

```
print("what is your name?")

name=input()

print("thank you",name,".")
```

I am not entirely sure that is the exact code but it does those three things. Thank you and sorry it is a bit basic. Also I am using 3.3.2 I think.

Comment: check the type of input

Comment: define `text`. is it only `no numbers`, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to test if a string is all alphabetic characters (letters):

```
>>> 'abcde'.isalpha()
True
>>> 'abcde1'.isalpha()
False
>>>
```

---

If you have a specific character set to test for, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
chars = set('abcde')  # Put the characters you want to test for in here
all(c in chars for c in name)
```

Also, I used a set instead of a regular string of characters to improve efficiency.  Sets have `O(1)` (constant) complexity with `in` where as strings have `O(n)` (linear) complexity.  In other words, it is faster to find things in a set than in a string.

---

Lastly, you can use [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) instead of typing out the whole alphabet:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>>
```

This becomes especially useful if you want to test for all the letters of the alphabet plus another character or so (such as a hyphen):

```
chars = set(ascii_letters + '-')
```

Comment: The second would probably be better since isalpha will not work for hyphens

Comment: Good point.  I've edited my answer to handle hyphens.

Comment: @iCodez : Except that since the string has a fixed and known size, the actual search complexity is O(1) with regard to the `name` string.

Comment: if the OP just wants to just check for numbers `if not any(x.isdigit() for x in s)` and allow all other characters

Comment: @njzk2 - No it isn't.  Doing `char in string` is always `O(n)` because `in` has to go through the string character by character until it finds what it is looking for.  Sets however have `O(1)` complexity because they use a hash-lookup.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - True.  But I went with my approach because he said he is working with names.  Using your approach, a user could enter symbols such as `$` or `%`, which are not a part of a normal name.

Comment: Time complexity seems quite irrelevant in this case, since n is going to be approximately zero, plus some epsilon (let's say ~60, ascii chars plus some punctuation and whitespace).

Comment: @JonKiparsky - I agree that it isn't a *huge* improvement, but it seems better that `chars` be a set.  I mean, `chars` is supposed to represent the set of characters to test for.  So, why not make it a set?  Also, for a one-time run, you won't get anything significant. However, you will surely notice the performance gain of the `O(1)` algorithm if you use this code repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: @iCodez No, I don't think you will, considering the case we're describing. The slowest element in this equation is the user, and there's not a lot of ways you can make time an issue.

Comment: @iCodez: `char in string` is O(n) where `n` is the size of the string. In this case, the string size is always 52, which is a constant. O(constant) = O(1). `n` is the size of the variable input `name`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to address this. One would be to do something like

```
if name.isalpha():
  # it's alphabetic
else:
  # it's not - prompt for new input
```

But this will reject some names that you might like, such as "John Smith" or "Kate O'Conner".

A more careful approach would be something like

```
if any(map (lambda c: c.isdigit(), name)):
  # there's a digit in there, reject it
else:
  # it's got no digits, but maybe it still has punctuation that you don't want?
  # do further checks as needed
```

You can also build a whitelist:

```
import string
allowed_chars = string.ascii_letters+"'"+ "-" + " "  
   # allow letters, single-quote, hyphen and space
if all([c in allowed_chars for c in name]):
  # passes the whitelist, allow it
```